# How to convert Vue class binding into strings for classlist?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I'm building a component that is going to set classes on the `body` element, which resides outside of the Vue app. As such, I can't use class bindings on the element, I have to use `element.classList`.

I have a prop that accepts classes the way Vue class binding does; a string, expression, array, or object (React has a separate library that does this called [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)).

For example:

```js
<BodyBridge background-class="bg-gray-300" />
<BodyBridge :background-class="isCertainPage && 'bg-gray-300'" />
<BodyBridge :background-class="isCertainPage ? 'bg-gray-300' : ''" />
<BodyBridge :background-class="['bg-gray-300', 'text-red-500']" />
<BodyBridge :background-class="{ 'bg-gray-300': isCertainPage }" />
<BodyBridge :background-class="['text-red-500', ['class-in-nested-array'], { 'bg-gray-300': isCertainPage }]" />
```

However, I need to evaluate those classes and get the string representations of them so that I can pass them like this:

```js
element.classList.add(...backgroundClasses)
```

Is there any way to reconcile the classes to a string or strings?

Comment: `Object.keys(backgroundClasses)` will return the keys (class names) of the object as an array of strings.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: There's no official way and no third-party util I'm aware of. You'll need a recursive function based on the specified rules

Comment: @yoduh no, I need to reconcile the conditional logic into strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding an implementation detail, but my idea would be to watch the value of the `background-class` prop in `<BodyBridge>`, loop the entries of the prop object, and for each key-value pair add to or remove from the body classList

**BodyBridge.vue**

```js
watch(
  () => props.backgroundClass,
  newValue => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(newValue)) {
      if (value) {
        document.body.classList.add(key)
      } else {
        document.body.classList.remove(key)
      }
    }
  },
  { immediate: true }
)
```

The conditional logic in the Parent

```
{ 'bg-gray-300': isCertainPage }
```

Would already be evaluated inside the Child component

```
{ 'bg-gray-300': true } // prop value
```

So for each `[key, value]` entry it should be a simple check on the truthiness of `value`.

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) (be sure to inspect the `<body>` inside the Playground's iframe, not the root `<body>` of the page)

Comment: My example may be too simple. The class bindings in Vue allow strings, expressions, arrays, objects and combinations of all of them. The react `classnames` library replicates this behaviour. I'll update my question.